# using sqlite's strftime function in android

Tags: android, sqlite, strftime

Hello I have inserted some dates in my database.

When I use sqlite3 in the format `YYY-MM-DD` in another table when I do my query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM SDay 
WHERE  strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)>=strftime('%Y-%m-%d','2013-02-21')
    AND  strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)<strftime('%Y-%m-%d','2013-09-15')
```

it works just fine.

On the other hand when i use the format `YYY-MM` in another table
then the

```
SELECT * 
FROM SMonth 
WHERE  strftime('%Y-%m', date)>=strftime('%Y-%m','2013-02') 
    AND  strftime('%Y-%m', date)<strftime('%Y-%m','2013-09')
```

will not work.Why does it happen and how could I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your second statement, `strftime` is provided with an invalid `timestring`. This causes the function to return `NULL`:

```
sqlite> .nullvalue <NULL>
sqlite> select strftime('%Y-%m','2013-02');
<NULL>
```

Just add the day to the date you provide and it will work properly:

```
sqlite> select strftime('%Y-%m','2013-02-01');
2013-02
```

You can find a list of valid `timestring` formats [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: is it strftime working with dots? For example   " strftime('%dd.%mm.%YYYY', Birthday) > date('now','-30 years')"